# What is this moss-like plant?

Tags: identification, moss

I found this weird mossy plant growing in my pot. It has a cool shape actually. There are crater-like pits on its leaf. I really liked it and want to know its name. I live in Istanbul, Turkey.

[image]

Comment: @pnuts Hi, I removed the green tick, you can edit now.

Comment: It is a liverwort...Both answers are correct!  Pnuts definitely got it and the common name (grins, Bamboo).  Not to worry, your answer will be undeleted shortly!  And I will upvote yours soon, pnuts.

Comment: @Alper91  This is very common in pots of plants in nurseries where they indiscriminately water way too often.  This plant not going to hurt anything.  I'd pull it before it produces spores but it does show what Bamboo is describing.  Too much water too often.  Are you trying to grow moss?

Comment: actually i am trying to grow bonsai with moss. i planted a very little piece of moss on the soil where bonsaies grow and it spread quicker than i expected. i try to maintain both bonsai and the moss. for a beautiful view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely Marchantia polymorpha, but that and the presence of moss means the soil in that container or pot or whatever it is is stagnant and waterlogged. It needs aerating by turning the soil over, preferably adding some balanced fertilizer at the same time, if you want to grow other plants in there. If you're quite happy with it growing there, and don't want to grow anything else in it other than possibly bog plants, then fine, leave it. It's quite an interesting plant in its own right.

UPDATE

In response to your query below, no, you shouldn't be worried  exactly, but if there are other plants growing in there, you might want to check the drainage is working properly in terms of holes in the container by checking they are not blocked, gently turn over the soil to remove the liverwort and moss. If your Chestnut, Black Cypress and Pine are just small seedlings, then best not add fertilizer at this stage - presumably you will shortly be pricking out those seedling plants into separate pots anyway.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion but in the same pot there are Chestnut, Black cypress and pine also. They are growed from seeds, and doing fine for now. Should I be worried?
,